# Why We Couldn't Create Pointer To Friend Functions Defined In A Class?

Tags: c++, function-pointers, friend

```cpp
struct A
{
  friend void f();
};

void f() {}
```

We could define a pointer to the `f()`:

```cpp
using FType = void(*)();
FType ptr_to_f = f;
```

But if we move the definition of the `f()` into the `A`, then we couldn't define any pointer to the `f()`:

```cpp
struct A
{
  friend void f()
  {
  }
};

using FType = void(*)();
FType ptr_to_f = f; //< error: ‘f’ was not declared in this scope
```

Why?

From [this(Pointer to friend function)](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/23265/) CPlusPlus forum:

> a friend declaration is not a prototype.

But I don't understand it and couldn't find any documentation about it in:

- [C++ Draft](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.friend#:access_control,friend_function)
- [Cppreferences](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend)

Comment: `struct` and `friend`, what is the purpose when all members are `public`

Comment: @macroland -- the purpose is to provide a simple example of the problem.